# To find number of continuous Repeating characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a String like this `str = "aabcccdfffeeeeettaaaattiioccc"`

I need output like this `Result ={aa: 1;b:1;ccc:2;d:1;fff:1;eeeee:1;tt:2;aaaa:1;ii:1;o:1;ccc:1}`

I have tried it like this so far:

```
def repeating_letters(the_string):
    temp = []
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(the_string)):
        if(the_string[i] == the_string[i]):
            if(the_string[i] == the_string[i+1]):
                temp = the_string[i]
                # count = count+1
                print(the_string[i])


if name__== "__main":
    the_string = "aaafassskfahfioejwwa"
    repeating_letters(the_string)
```

Comment: Do you have a question or just felt like sharing?

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: def repeating_letters(the_string):
 temp = []
 count = 0
 for i in range(len(the_string)):
  
  if(the_string[i] == the_string[i]):

   if(the_string[i] == the_string[i+1]):
    temp = the_string[i]
    # count = count+1
    print(the_string[i])




if __name__== "__main__":
 the_string = "aaafassskfahfioejwwa"
 # couting_letter(the_string)
 repeating_letters(the_string)

Comment: I have inserted your code in your question, can you check that the indent is right, as the comment doesn't save multiple spaces, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hints

I would follow this steps:

1. Create a list where I will store my partial strings
2. Start iterating the string

   - Store the initial position and the current character
   - Keep iterating until the character is different
   - Store in the list the partial string from the initial position you stored until 1 less than the current position
   - Update the initial position to the current one and the current character
3. Use the list to create a `collections.Counter`

About your code, `the_string[i] == the_string[i]` will always be true.

---

### SPOILER: solution

```
from collections import Counter


def repeating_letters(the_string):
    partials = []
    initial = 0
    for i, character in enumerate(the_string):
        if character == the_string[initial]:
            continue
        partials.append(the_string[initial:i])
        initial = i
    partials.append(the_string[initial:])  # Needed for the last partial string
    return Counter(partials)
```

As @prahantrana mentions in a comment, getting the partials can be done in a one-liner with the `groupby` method from the `itertools` library.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby


def repeating_letters(the_string):
    return Counter(''.join(group) for _, group in groupby(the_string))
```

Or

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby


def repeating_letters(the_string):
    return Counter(char*len(list(group)) for char, group in groupby(the_string))
```

I'm not sure which of them is faster.

Comment: I wanted the user to learn from this problem. I provided a quite optimized solution. The only remaining change you could do is removing the intermediate list and add partials to the `Counter` directly but it looks less intuitive.

Comment: you can use     `string =  [''.join(group) for key, group in groupby(text)]` single line solution

Comment: @prashantrana importing itertools just for this doesn't seem neccesary, and also providing a coded solution helps more the author than providing a library that does what he wants, IMO. But yes, partials can be achieved as you mention.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

def splitter(text):
    """
    text: str
    return : frequency of continous characters
    """
    string =  [''.join(group) for key, group in groupby(text)]
    return Counter(string)


l = 'aaaabcccdfffeeeeettfffaaaattiioccceeeeeeaaaa'

print(splitter(l))
```

output

```
Counter({'aaaa': 3, 'ccc': 2, 'fff': 2, 'tt': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'eeeee': 1, 'ii': 1, 'o': 1, 'eeeeee': 1})
```

other way , coded method, not using any library

```
from collections import Counter


def function(string):
        """
        string: str
        return: frequency of continous same character
        """
        res = []
        tmp = []
        if len(string)==0:
            return Counter('')
        val = string[0]
        for i in range(1, len(string)):
            if string[i] == val:
                tmp.append(val)
                val =string[i]
            else:
                tmp.append(val)
                res.append(tmp)
                tmp = []
                val = string[i]
        tmp.append(val)
        res.append(tmp)
        p = [''.join(i) for i in res]

        return Counter(p)


l ='aaaabcccdfffeeeeettfffaaaattiioccceeeeeeaaaa'


print(function(l))
```

output

```
Counter({'aaaa': 3, 'ccc': 2, 'fff': 2, 'tt': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'eeeee': 1, 'ii': 1, 'o': 1, 'eeeeee': 1})
```

Comment: An answer with non-PEP8 python code, no text, unused imports, non-self-defining variable names, etc.

Comment: I added some extra PEP8-related edits, removed the downvote. I still think there are some things to be improved but you solved the most critical parts

Comment: i have input like this  str = "aaaabcccdfffeeeeettfffaaaattiioccceeeeeeaaaa"  but i get wrong  output like this Counter({'aaaa': 2, 'ccc': 2, 'fff': 2, 'tt': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'eeeee': 1, 'ii': 1, 'o': 1, 'eeeeee': 1, 'aaa': 1})  there are 3 times 4 a present but it shows only 2  times

Comment: @anwarshawn , added a new way to solve this problem